# std::variant declaration is not found by compiler

Tags: c++, std, variant

What I am trying to do is very simple, I need to create a vector that can hold different types of data. So I read about std::variant and am trying to use it, however, when declaring my "std::vector< std::variant< typenames > >", the compiler complains about not finding the declaration for variant<> even though I included the variant  library.
(errors are "use of undeclared identifier variant" with implicit namespace, and "no member named 'variant' in namespace 'std'" with explicit namespace). My Clang version is 11, and I am using c++17, so I don't know what I could be missing here. For what it's worth, I am currently using VScode 1.53. This is my c_cpp_properties.json :

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I have tried also changing the cpp version in the default GUI provided by vscode to manage the cpp compiler, that made no difference.

What I am doing is something similar to this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

struct c {
    std::vector< std::variant<glm::vec2, glm::vec3, glm::vec4>> v;
};
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or had this problem before and knows a solution?

**Solution:**
Turns out specifying the cpp standard on the file c_cpp_properties.json is not enough. You have to add "-std=c++17" to tasks.json as well, after "-g", like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-std=c++17",
                     ...
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your compiler?

Comment: If the compiler doesn't complain about `#include <variant>` it shouldn't complain about `std::variant` later on. Do you have a file named `variant` in your project?

Comment: And where are the declarations of all these types in the `glm` namespace? Instead of showing "similar to this code", you should show a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** and get the same compilation error.

Comment: I haven't any other file or class named variant, and the fact it doesn't complain about the #include but about the variant is what is confusing me. The types I showed are the ones I intend to use, but if i declare, for instance, variant<int, float, double> same error pops up by the compiler
about the first question, i just checked and my compiler is also up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Clang expert, but try using the option `-std=c++17`.

According to [this](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#:%7E:text=Clang%20fully%20implements%20all%20published,upcoming%20C%2B%2B20%20standard.&text=Experimental%20work%20is%20also%20under,of%20the%20C%2B%2B%20programming%20language.) the default seems to be C++98.

Comment: I had already changed in c_cpp_properties.json as I said in the post, however apparently that is not enough, so with your suggestion I changed the file tasks.json, adding "-std=c++17" after "-g". All errors disappeared. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work fine in MSVC:

```
#include <variant>

struct c {
    std::vector< std::variant<int, float>> v;
}
```

It seems like the compiler might be throwing a fit about the template type nesting(wild guess here). Maybe try the following as a workaround:

```
#include <variant>

struct c {
    typedef std::variant< int, float> TwoPartVariant;
    std::vector< TwoPartVariant> v;
};
```

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately same error appears: no template named variant on namespace std
what is really strange though, is that after changing the line from c++11 to c++17 on the cpp properties file, the editor colorized the variant name, as if recognizing it, but still don't find the declaration